# P-comfirmpopup is not working on OnRemove property of P-chip

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

I’m using PrimeNG in Angular CLI: 11.2.19, Node: 14.17.3
The two components are
P-chip and  P-confirmPopup when I’m using this code the popup in showing at the end of the screen and removing the filter then and there not waiting for the “accept ” or “reject ”. on the other hand for tag <i> it’s working fine.

I need help with two things first it should show the confirmPopup in the div and the other is that it should wait for the confirmPop to be answered. Or how can I remove the “times icon of p-chip”
Used iconRemove property it’s not working.
If there is something else that I can add please let me know.
Thanks in advance for the help.
The component.html
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8oBL.png)

The component.ts
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLxSI.png)

I need help with two things first it should show the confirmPopup in the div and the other is that it should wait for the confirmPop to be answered. Or how can I remove the “times icon of p-chip” Used iconRemove property it’s not working. If there is something else that I can add please let me know. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
.p-chips-token-icon{
    display: none   
  }
```

it solved my problem. Thanks